# ace.edit can't find div #javascript-editor in mat-tab

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular6, ace-editor

I'm trying to create an ace editor which is throwing an error when used inside angular material

**ace.edit can't find div #javascript-editor**

I have my code here [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jkhzsw) (check console for the error)

> app.component.html

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab label="Editor">
    <h4>Custom Editor</h4>
    <div id="javascript-editor" style="height: 300px;"></div>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

> app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import * as ace from 'brace';
import 'brace/mode/javascript';
import 'brace/theme/monokai';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit() {
    const editor = ace.edit('javascript-editor');
    editor.getSession().setMode('ace/mode/javascript');
    editor.setTheme('ace/theme/monokai');
  }
}
```

Comment: Would be better to show some of the code example here too, so that the question stays useful even after the stackBlitz is discontinued, also did you ask a colleague to upvote your question, or is this somehow a very common problem to immediately get an upvote?

Comment: I added code from stackblitz asked and no I didn't ask for any upvote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling ace.edit when the javascript-editor element is not created yet, try calling it from `ngAfterViewInit` instead of `ngOnInit`.